# How to style text inserted with innerHTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code for a header:

```
<div id="title-text">
    The Cuttlefisher Paradise
</div>
<div id="choices">
    <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <!-- 5 more items -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want this to be the header about 10 different web pages. I cannot use `<frame>` or `<iframe>` for graphical reasons.

For an example of what I want to do, I am currently using `document.getElementById("home").setAttribute("class", "active")` to style the active tab, but when the header (the block of code just above) is inserted into a div using `innerHTML`, `document.getElementById` does not work (returns null).

What simple method is there to either put the header (without `<frame>` or `<iframe>`) on multiple pages or get `document.getElementById` to find ids inserted with `innerHTML`?

Comment: as far as I know it will; however, you are trying to clone a node with it's *unique* id.  Only one element in a document may have a particular id, and if you need several to have the same identifying handle, use a class instead.  This may be your problem, but idk.

Comment: Why don't you insert them using the DOM instead then? It will allow you to use .getElementById.

Comment: Are you using a server-side language such as PHP? You should be including the menu on each page using server-side code.

Comment: @Dan : Do you mean commands like `createElement`? I don't want to manually have to constuct the unordered list with lots of JavaScript. That sounds like it might end up being a very messy mix of HTML and JavaScript. @thirtydot : I preferably want to just use HTML, JavaScript, and CSS for this.

Comment: <?php include('myheader.html'); ?>

Comment: Yes I am talking about those. If they have to be flexible on every site retrieve them with ajax and transport the information for the list using json. you can then automatically add the elements defined in your json and there is no big work involved. If it's exactly the same on each side why don't you include it in the page from the start? It's hard to give a good advice here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put all that content into a single javascript string and get all the quoting and line breaks right to make it a legal javascript string, then there should be no problem assigning it to innerHTML and the browser will parse all the tags and create the HTML for you.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QmGvF/.

Javascript code called from page ready handler:

```
var newHTML = '<div id="title-text"> \
    The Cuttlefisher Paradise \
</div> \
<div id="choices"> \
    <ul> \
        <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li> \
        <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li> \
        <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li> \
        <!-- 5 more items --> \
    </ul> \
</div>';

document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = newHTML;

var home = document.getElementById("home");
home.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

Comment: It creates the HTML for me no problem, but `getElementById` doesn't work on any of the newly inserted elements.

Comment: See the updated jsFiddle.  I'm able to retrieve the "home" ID and set an attribute on it just fine.  There must be something else going on with your code/HTML.

Comment: My problem ended up being that I was setting the class name for an id that didn't exist (i.e. I took away a menu button but left the styling for it). Thank you for showing me how to use `.className` (I had no clue that it exists).

Comment: Cool, glad you got it figured.